# Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference in IE EDGE BROWSER

Tags: javascript

I have one method for get value from attribute.

```
function ZZTA_CreateTree(tree_src, tree) {
 // if (tree_src.text.charAt(0) == "&" ||
 if (String(tree_src.text).charAt(0) == "&" ||
      tree_src.text == "") return 0;

//  var temp_list = tree_src.text.split('#');
var temp_list = String(tree_src.text).split('#');
var temp_len  = temp_list.length - 1;

  for (i=0; i<temp_len; i++)
  treeÝi¨ = new TreeItem(temp_listÝi¨);

  temp_list = null;
  return i;
}
```

Comment: What is `tree_src`?

Comment: clearly it's undefined or null :p

Comment: Show how you call `ZZTA_CreateTree`